# toggleClass() with next() does not work Jquery

Tags: jquery

I've this code :

```
<ul class="mobile">
     <li>
        link 1
        <span>></span>
        <ul class="submenu">
           <li></li>
           <li></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li>
        link 2
        <span>></span>
        <ul class="submenu">
           <li></li>
           <li></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li>
        link 3
        <span>></span>
        <ul class="submenu">
           <li></li>
           <li></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>


$('.mobile > li > span').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.submenu').toggleClass('active');
});
```

What I want to do is to toggle a class called "active" when I click on the `span` but it does not work.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: So, what does happen? Are you getting errors in the browser console? Is it adding the class active to your submenu ul?

Comment: the toggle fire only once , its fade in but not fade out

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/acx08dmf/ appears to work here.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r7mx7vyc/1/ fiddle works for me as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.mobile > li > span').click(function(event) {
    $(this).next('ul').toggleClass('main');
});
```

```css
.main {
    font-size: 120%;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mobile">
     <li>
        link 1
        <span>>Click Me</span>
        <ul class="submenu">
           <li>hello</li>
           <li>hello</li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li>
        link 2
        <span>>click me</span>
        <ul class="submenu">
           <li>hello </li>
           <li>hello</li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li>
        link 3
        <span>>Click me</span>
        <ul class="submenu">
           <li>hello </li>
           <li>hello</li>
        </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and my favorite way of doing this is as following. Try this.

```
<ul class="mobile">
     <li>
        link 1
        <span data-menu="1st" class="spanclick">></span>
        <ul class="submenu" id="1st">
           <li></li>
           <li></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li>
        link 2
        <span data-menu="2nd" class="spanclick">></span>
        <ul class="submenu" id="2nd">
           <li></li>
           <li></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li>
        link 3
        <span data-menu="3rd" class="spanclick">></span>
        <ul class="submenu" id="3rd">
           <li></li>
           <li></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>


$('span.spanclick').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var cl = $(this).attr('data-menu');
    $('ul#'+cl).toggleClass('active');
});
```